# How to get all cars which is not booked or available between a datetime

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table first is cars and second is booking and my search fields is

- Location
- type
- pick datetime
- drop datetime

so please let me know how to get available cars which is not booked now between a date time if car booked then it should not be in list. list should be come only available cars by search.

Cars Table

```
----------------------------------------------
id | name | type | location | pincode
----------------------------------------------
 1    A    plain   delhi       110093
 2    B    plain   deldi       110093
 3    C    plain   deldi       110093
 4    D    plain   deldi       110093
 5    E    plain   deldi       110093
```

### Booking Table

```
id | car_id | user_id  |      pick_date    | drop_date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1    1         1        2016-05-10 13:00:00  2016-05-12 16:00:00    
 2    1         1        2016-05-12 18:00:00  2016-05-12 23:00:00
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Neither booked nor available??

Comment: Looks like homework. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the your_startdate and your_enbdate you should insert your date range

```
Select cars.* 
from cars
Left join booking on cars.id=booking.id and pick_date between your_startdate and your_enddate
Where booking.id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query...

Find the cars id's from booking that are booked on given dates and then find all the cars from cars table where id not equal to booked cars..

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT car_id FROM booking 
                                    WHERE pick_date >= '2015-06-03'
                                    AND drop_date <= '2015-06-05'
                                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

According your search variables, first select `car_id` from Booking table between pick datetime and drop datetime.

Now you have a list of `car_id` which is booked between that date and time.

Use a loop and make a select query from cars table where `id != car_id` and location and type will be as your search variables.

Answer (score 0):

use between query and know which car are booked and also know the specific time car available are not .

**given_time_here_search_time = "2016-05-11 15:00:00";** //user input

query should be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM cars
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT car_id 
FROM booking 
WHERE given_time_here_search_time  
between pick_date
AND drop_date ) and location='delhi' and type='plain';
```